# Excel formula using a ranged percentage

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to work out a % of a value entered - measured against a range with the lower range resulting in a score of 0% and the top range being 100%.

Hopefully the picture will explain it well.

For example say someone enters the price of £19.63 you get 100% if you enter £17.13 you get 0% and a scale between.

[image]

Comment: Subtract the min from the entered value and divide that by the range.

Comment: That's giving me odd ranges and percentages

Comment: That seems like the way to do it though, if I understand what you're trying to do.  You have a max of 19.63 and a min of 17.13, so a range of max-min = 2.50.  (min-min)/range = 0%, (max-min)/range = 100%, (x-min)/range = x%.

Comment: Sorry. I'm still not quite getting it into hat formula.  My results end up with strange % .

Comment: Perhaps we aren't understanding the question.  Maybe you can give some examples of your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, but here is what I have: compare the entered price with the lowest and divide my maximum range allowed. Which will give you the expected percentage.

As you change the price in C1, your Awarded % will update.

[image]